# Parameter '?...' has already been defined

Tags: c#, mysql

I found some solutions and suggestions on the Internet concering this problem, however, I could not yet manage to apply this to my solution. I wrote a personal MySQL wrapper which features this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DatabaseFieldSet>> QueryParamsAsync(string query, string[] parameter,
        string[] value)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            await ConnectAsync();
        var rows = new List<DatabaseFieldSet>();

        using (var cmd = CreateCommand(query))
        {
            foreach (var str in parameter)
            {
                foreach (var val in value)
                {
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(str, MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = val;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(str, val);
                }
            }
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                uint currentRowIndex = 0;

                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var row = new DatabaseFieldSet(currentRowIndex);
                    var fields = new List<DatabaseField>();

                    for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
                    {
                        var column = new DatabaseReference((uint) i);
                        fields.Add(new DatabaseField(reader[i], column, row));
                    }

                    row.Fields = fields;
                    rows.Add(row);

                    currentRowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

I tried to add

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

at different locations, none worked or was throwing fatal error while executing. I hope somebody can tell me where to put this single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It rather should be like below. Your double `foreach` causing the issue and you are eventually trying to add the same parameter again and so the error. You rather should define a counter variable and access every item in your value array.

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var str in parameter)
        {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(str, val[i]);
                i++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was totally off!